# Optimal parallelisation of communication from randomly distributed particles to regular grid

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I am working on parallelizing my particle-in-cell code which I use to do simulations of deformation within the earth in 2D and 3D. Several routines of the code are easy to parallelize using OpenMP and scale very well. However, I have run into problems in a crucial part of the code that deals with interpolation from particles to a grid cells. The particles are moving around for each iteration (according to a velocity field). Many calculations are most effecient to perform on a regular, non-deforming grid. Therefore, each iteration involves communication from "randomly"  distributed particles to the grid cells.

The problem can be illustrated in the following simplified 1D code:

```
//EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES (all previously allocated and initialized, 1D arrays)
//double *markerval; // Size Nm. Particle values. Are to be interpolated to the grid
//double *grid; // Size Ng=Nm/100 Grid values. 
//uint *markerpos; // Size Nm. Position of particles relative to grid (each particle
// knows what grid cell it belongs to) possible values are 0,1,...Ng-1

//#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(e)
for (e=0; e<Nm; e++) {
    //#pragma omp atomic
    grid[markerpos[e]]+=markerval[e];
}
```

The particle positions are random in the worst case scenario, but typically, particles neighboring each other in memory, also neighbor each other in space and hence also in grid memory.

How do I parallelize this procedure efficiently? Several particles map to the same grid cell, so there is a nonzero chance of race conditions and cache swapping if the above loop is directly parallelized. Making the update atomic prevents race conditions, but makes the code much slower than the sequential case.

I also tried to make a private copy of grid values for each thread and then add them up subsequently. This, however, probably requires too much memory in the code to be used, and for this example, it did not scale so well with the number of threads (for reasons of which I am uncertain).

A third option might be to map from the grid to the particles and then loop through grid indices instead of particle indices. However, this, I fear, would be quite involved and require a major change of the code, and I am uncertain how much it would help, since it would also require the use of sort routines which would be computationally expensive as well.

Has anybody got any experience with this or a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be to map the iterations manually upon the threads:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(Nm,Ng,markerval,markerpos,grid)
{
  int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  int rank     = omp_get_thread_num();
  int factor   = Ng/nthreads;

  for (int e = 0; e < Nm; e++) {
    int pos = markerpos[e];
    if ( (pos/factor)%nthreads == rank )
      grid[pos]+=markerval[e];
  }
}
```

A few remarks:

1. The iteration of the `for` loop are not shared among threads. Instead **each thread** does all the iterations.
2. The conditional inside the `for` loop decides **which thread** will update location `pos` of the `grid` array. This location **belongs to one thread only**, thus the `atomic` protection is not needed.
3. The formula `(pos/factor)%nthreads` is just a simple heuristic. Any function of `pos` that returns a value in the range `0,...,nthreads-1` could in fact be substituted to this expression without compromising the validity of the final results (so feel free to change it if you have a better shot). Note that a poor choice of this function may result in *load-balancing* issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a very simple and elegant solution to the problem that does not require a major change of my existing code. For the above simple code example, the speedup is not that good (due to the extra work involved in mapping the threads), but adding some extra local calculations locally at each particle or cell clearly makes this work. For my actual code where this will be implemented, there are is lot of local operations, so it should work.

Comment: This solution will probably have problem of load balance

Comment: A difference between my actual code and the present example is that each particle maps to four neighboring grid cells (in 2d). For this reason, I will need make a sort of "red/black" division of the thread to grid mapping, so that threads are not working on neighboring grid cells. This will require an extra synchronization, but I still expect it to perform well.

Comment: Dreamcrash: Do you by "load balance" mean that there is a chance that some threads will finish before others and that this will reduce performance?

Comment: Is your algorithm this similar to Successive Over-relaxation algorithm? Because if it was you could consider the use of block partition

Comment: By load balance i mean imagining you have 2 threads and that int pos = markerpos[e]; generate most pos that will be assign to thread 0 than one. Maybe it does not make since in your algorithm.

Comment: @dreamcrash You are right saying that it _may_ have load-balancing issues. As positions are mapped to threads by a function, then you must ensure that this function is good enough not to compromise your performance. On the other hand you don't need any locking...

Answer (score 1):

I have parallelized a molecular dynamic algorithm with OpenMP also. First, you have to analyze the algorithm **bottleneck** (*e.g.,* memory bound and CPU bound). In this way you will know where to improve.

Initially, my MD was memory bound, so I gain about `2x` in speed just by changing the data layout from an array of structures (AOS) to a structure of arrays (SOA) (**due spatial locality**). I also applied, for the inputs that only fitted in RAM, a blocking technique. The original algorithm calculated the pairs of forces between every particle as it follows:

```
for(int particleI = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
 for(int particleJ = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
     calculate_force_between(i,j);
```

Basically, with the block technique, we agglomerate the force calculation by blocks of particles. For instance, calculating all the pares of forces among the first 10 particles, then the next 10 and so on.

The use of this **blocks technique** promotes better use of **temporal locality**, since with this approach it is possible to realize more calculations for the same particles in a shorter amount of time. Therefore, decreasing the possibility that the value that we are trying to access is no longer in the cache.

Now that I have a MD CPU bound, I can try to improve it by using `multi-threads`, but first, you need to:

1. Verify where your algorithm spends most of its execution time;
2. Find the tasks that can be done in parallel and determine their
   **granularity** (to check if its parallelization is justified);
3. **Load Balance**, ensuring a good load balancing of work among threads;
4. Minimizing the use of synchronization.

I was having problems scaling my MD because of load balancing problems. Some threads were doing more work than others. The solution?

You can try the **dynamic for** from openMP. Note that in OpenMP you can specify the chunk of work to be assigned to threads. However, you have to be careful in defining the chunk! With the dynamic *for*, a chunk too small can cause synchronization overhead, and too big can cause load balance problems.

I also had problems with synchronization overhead. I was using critical and the algorithm did not scale. I replaced that critical with a finer grain synchronization, namely locks, one for each particle. I had some improvements with that approach.

As the last approach (to deal with synchronization overhead), I use data redundancy. Each particle did its work and saved the result in a private temporary data structure. In the end, all threads reduced their values. From all the versions this was the one that gave me the best results.

I was able to achieve good speedups in CPU, but nothing compared with those that I achieved with the GPU version.

With the information that you have provided, I would do something like this:

```
omp_lock_t locks [grid_size]; // create an array of locks
int g;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (e=0; e<Nm; e++)
{
    g = markerpos[e];

    omp_set_lock(&locks[g]);
    grid[g]+=markerval[e];
    omp_unset_lock(&locks[g]);
}
```

From, what I understood the problem is that you have to use `atomic` to ensure that multiple threads do not access simultaneously the same grip position. As a possible solution, you can create an array of locks and each time a thread has to access one position of the grid it requests and acquires the lock associated with that position. Another solution can be:

```
double grid_thread[grid_size][N_threads]; // each thread have a grid
// initialize the grid_threads to zeros

#pragma omp parallel
{
    int idT = omp_get_thread_num();
    int sum;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (e=0; e<Nm; e++)
        grid_thread[markerpos[e]][idT]+=markerval[e]; // each thread compute in their 
                                                     // position
    for(int j = 0; j <Nm; j++)
    { 
        sum = 0;
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum) 
        for (i = 0; i < idT; i++)                   // Store the result from all
           sum += grid_thread[j][i];                // threads for grid position j

         #pragma barrier                            // Ensure mutual exclusion

         #pragma master
         grid[j] +=sum;                             // thread master save the result  
                                                    // original grid
         #pragma barrier                            // Ensure mutual exclusion
      }
   }
}
```